# Swift SpriteKit 別クラスのメソッドを使用したい

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

別クラスのメソッドを使用してNodeをdidMoveで表示させたいのですが、下記コードでは表示されません。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

**現状のコード**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let enemy = Enemy()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.enemy.addEnemy()
    }
}

class Enemy: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let enemyNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")

    func addEnemy() {
        enemyNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        enemyNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        enemyNode.zPosition = 1.0
        addChild(enemyNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: ある`SKScene`が(今の場合`GameScene`)表示されているときに、別の`SKScene`(`Enemy`)のインスタンスを作って、そのなかで`addChild`のようなメソッドを呼んでも、画面に表示されることはありません。なんのために別クラスを作ったのか、なぜそれが`SKScene`のサブクラスでなければいけなかったのか、そのクラスを他にどのように使っているのか、などがわかれば、回答と言えるようなことが書けるかもしれません。

Comment: OOPerさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通りですね、、
コードを綺麗にしたいと考え、Nodeの情報をまとめようと考えてました。
抽象的な考えですので、また勉強して考え直します。
ご迷惑をおかけ致しました。

Comment: どう言った意図でクラス分割をしたのかがわからないと回答が書けないのでコメントしただけで、ご迷惑なんかではありませんよ。特にクラスをできるだけ機能ごとにまとめる、と言うのはアプリが大規模になってくると必要なことです。あなたのアプリに使えるかどうか分かりませんが、例えばの例を回答として示させてもらいますので、参考にしてみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

いただいたコメントの内容から、

- `Enemy`を別クラスとしたのは *コードを綺麗にしたいと考え、Nodeの情報をまとめようと考えて* のこと
- `SKScene`のサブクラスにしたのは、`addChild(_:)`メソッドを使いたかったから

と言うことだと解釈しました。

---

*Nodeの情報をまとめ* るのであれば、別質問であったような、`SKSpriteNode`のサブクラスとするのはいかがでしょうか?

コメントに書いた「別の`SKScene`のインスタンスを作って、そのなかで`addChild`のようなメソッドを呼んでも、画面に表示されることはありません」というのを解決する方法ですが、`addChild`は`SKScene`の公開メソッドなので、「ある`SKSceneが`(今の場合`GameScene`)表示されているとき」そのインスタンスそのものを引数として渡してやれば、`addChild(_:)`メソッドを呼ぶことができます。(別のインスタンスを作ってはいけない。)

```
class EnemyNode: SKSpriteNode {
    static let enemy = EnemyNode(imageNamed: "enemy")!

    static func addEnemy(to scene: SKScene) {
        let enemyNode = EnemyNode.enemy
        enemyNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        enemyNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        enemyNode.zPosition = 1.0
        scene.addChild(enemyNode)
    }
}
```

`GameScene`の側では、こんなふうに使います。

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        EnemyNode.addEnemy(to: self) //<- `self`が表示されている`SKScene`のインスタンスそのものを表す
    }
}
```

---

上記の方法だとstatic変数`EnemyNode.enemy`に`EnemyNode`のインスタンスを保持しているので、アプリ全体で1個だけ`EnemyNode`が存在する場合にしか使えません。

`EnemyNode`が複数になる場合のことを考えたら、こうした方が良いかもしれません。

```
class EnemyNode: SKSpriteNode {
    //このメソッドの中で毎回`EnemyNode`のインスタンスを作成する
    static func addEnemy(to scene: SKScene) -> EnemyNode {
        let enemyNode = EnemyNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
        enemyNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        enemyNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        enemyNode.zPosition = 1.0
        scene.addChild(enemyNode)
        //作成したインスタンスを戻り値として返す
        return enemyNode
    }
}
```

呼び出す方の`GameScene`の側は、

```
    var enemyNode: EnemyNode?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        enemyNode = EnemyNode.addEnemy(to: self)

        //...
    }
```

---

どちらかのやり方を取り入れられそうであれば、試してみてください。

Comment: @OOperさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。
私の望んでおりましたご回答を頂けました。
今回もありがとうございました。
今後より見やすいコードを描ける様に精進して行きます！